# How to hide third party api fetch requests in react with nginx

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker

I setting up React app and Node js for api server, also I deployed it on Docker.

How to intercept React api requests with nginx, and send them to node js server, while the backend should not be accessible from the browser

Please, give some links or github repositories.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. React.js runs in the browser so if your api isn't accessible from the browser react won't be able to access it either.

Comment: Maybe there is way to 'wrap' react app in nginx, and forward requests to node js?

Comment: you may want to look into server-side rendering. then you could render your html using react on the server, making all your api calls from there, but have your api not accessible from the browser. as long as all the api calls are can be made before you send your initial html response from your server this would work. If you need to send user input to the server, then what you're describing is simply not possible. It's one of the major limitations of browser-based webapps. the server simply has no way of distinguishing between a request from your app and a malicious request froma user

Answer (score 1):

Can you specify what does `backend should not be accessible from the browser`? back end is not accessible from the browser, if you mean hide request uris there are no way to do it, only option is to encode uris and uglify code

Comment: For example, in react app fetch('localhost:4000/api/get-user'), nodejs server should handle this request, but if I enter localhost:4000/api/get-user in brwoser address bar, server should not answer anything. Can I somehow 'wrap' react app in nginx, and forward requests from react app to nodejs? Sorry for my English.

Comment: @Shevtsov you can use post method in this case as post url will not work from address bar

Comment: i do not think that is possible, because you created api with nodejs and only way to get data from that api is to fetch it (with react), by default browser is not responsible to fetch api for you

Comment: i answered what i understood from his question but if he means something else in `backend should not be accessible from the browser` this, i could answer that too if he specifies. and as i admitted the purpose he wants to achieve is impossible (i do not like this word but it is)